# how to append node to a specific place in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file like this, in it there is more than one table and I am trying to add a new node at the end of a specific table in the xml file. The user will choose the table and enter his data into a `DataGridView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table name="emloyees">
    <emloyees>
        <emp_num>employee 1</emp_num>
        <department>sales</department>
        <salary>1000</salary>
    </employees>
    <employees>
        <emp_num>employee 2</emp_num>
        <department>IT</department>
        <salary>2000</salary>
    </employees>

    ((for example I want to add new employees node here))

    <table name="projects">
        <projects>
            <proj_num>project 1</proj_num>
            <name>hosbital system</name>
            <num_mempers>5 members</num_mempers>
        </projects>
        <projects>
        <proj_num>project 2</proj_num>
            <name>library system</name>
            <num_mempers>4 members</num_mempers>
        </projects>
   </table>
</table>
```

I wrote this code, but instead of inserting a new node, the last node of the table gets replaced with the new node instead. How do I fix this?

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("Data.xml");
    string tablename = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    XmlNodeList row = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tablename);
    int c = row.Count;
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        XmlNodeList child = row[c - 1].ChildNodes;
        XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement(tablename);
        for (int k = 0; k < child.Count; k++)
        {
            XmlElement node = doc.CreateElement(child[k].ToString());
            child[k].InnerText = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].Value.ToString();
            element.AppendChild(node);
        }
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        root.AppendChild(element);
        doc.Save("Data.xml");
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added !!");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the XML structure is correct? `<table name="projects">` inside of `<table name="emloyees">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is here.

```
for (int k = 0; k < child.Count; k++)
{
   XmlElement node = doc.CreateElement(child[k].ToString());
   child[k].InnerText = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].Value.ToString(); // < here
   element.AppendChild(node);
}
```

You are setting the `child[k]'s` inner text, not the value of the `node` you created.

Change `child[k]` to `node`

```
node.InnerText = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].Value.ToString();
```

Your title asks to place the node at a specific place, but your code isn't doing it. You'll need to use the [parentNode.InsertAfter(newNode, refNode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

So instead of `root.AppendChild(element);`. Which puts the node at the bottom of the file, use `root.InsertAfter(element, child[child.Count - 1])` to put the new node after the last child type you are setting.

[AppendChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN docs.

Comment: thank's for your answer I did that , but the node added at the beginning of the file after -<table name="employees"> and the child node tags <System.Xml.XmlElement>....<System.Xml.XmlElement>    @Churk Savage

Comment: @SaraAshraf Um, yeah. That's because `k` is a `for` loop variable. And we were trying to use `k` outside the `for` loop. This is probably better `child[child.Count - 1]`